# Health Kit send weight value

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I am trying to integrate HealthKit to my application.
I am able to fetch data from health kit app about my weight and steps.

Trying to edit weight value from my app to HealthKit apples app.
Its says `domain=com.apple.healthkit code=4 unauthorized`.

Do I need to have provision profile in order to edit data of health kit from another app?

Any one please suggest how to edit example: weight from yourOwn App into Health Kit app.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit"? A snippet of the code you use to interact with HealthKit would help us understand what you are attempting.